# Docker Swarm/NestJS - First TCP message of the day is always rest

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, nestjs, docker-swarm

I am running a docker swarm with two nodes and several microservices that communicate with each other using TCP.

Micorservice A sends messages to microservices B, C and D and waits for a response. The microservices are only active for a few hours each day after which they remain silent. All four microservices are based on Nest.js and use the same settings for building and running the images.

Each day when they begin doing things micorservice A can successfully send messages to B and C but not D. The first message of the day between A and D always fails and the TCP connection is reset. After the first call I can see that A initiates a handshake after which everything works fine. I do not observe the same pattern with microservices B and C.

Below is the tcpdump from microservice A. Note that port 2003 is the port micorservice D is using. Also worrth mentioning is that while there are two RSTs in the screenshot before the hadshake they relate to the same inital request. In the tcpdump from microservice D the initial request is not found and the dumpt begins with the handshake.

I am wondering if this is a docker swarm issue or the application issue?

I am really not sure how to tackle this issue so any insights are greatlly appreaciated :)

[TCP dumpt from microservice A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seIRU.png)